# mcollective agent parameter definition

Tags: puppet, mcollective

The following ddl

```
action 'ant', :description => "Runs ant in the application directory" do
  input :application,
      :prompt      => "Application(s)",
      :description => "Application's instance name(s)",
      :type        => :string,
      :validation  => '^[a-z0-9_,\-]+$',
      :maxlength   => 500,
      :optional    => false
```

can be used inside an agent to get the command line parameter `application`

```
  # entry point for the ant target
  action 'ant' do
    # find eligible applications
    applications = request[:application].split(',').select{|a| valid_application?(a) }
```

The command command can be started with `mco <agentname> -a applicationname1,applicationname2`and so on. Issuing `mco <agentname> --help` gives me :

```
$ mco ehyp --help
Manage an <internal> application
Application Options
    -a, --application APPLICATION    Application to manage
```

I do not find the "link" between `-a` or `--application` and `request[:application]`. Where is it defined how to inteprete these command line switches ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is defined in `MCollective::Application` there you define :

```
option :application,
     :description => 'Application to manage',
     :arguments   => ['-a', '--application APPLICATION'],
     :required    => true

option :destination,
     :description => 'Ant target ("destination") to call',
     :arguments   => ['-d', '--destination TARGET'],
     :required    => true
```